# Setting up pre-requisites for creating viewer using suite-sdk

Tags: installation, boundless-suite, sdk

I am creating a Viewer using the `suite-sdk` from the following [tutorial](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/usermanual/tutorials/clientsdk.html#apps-sdk-client-script), which says

The Client SDK should be installed onto a machine where the development will occur. This is typically bundled with the OpenGeo Suite itself (under the sdk subdirectory)

I have installed the OpenGeo and so I wanted to know,

1. where is the sdk sub directory in the Opengeo suite that i have installed located in Ubuntu?
2. I have JDK version,

java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

1. ant -version -> 1.8.2

**Edit:**

I am not sure what the doc meant when it said extract the sdk dir to /opt/opengeo/suite/sdk, but I copied the /usr/share/opengeo-suite/sdk to the /opt/ dir, by creating opengeo, suite dirs. Is this the right method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to leave the sdk in the /usr/share/opengeo-suite/sdk directory, so you get updates when you update the OpenGeo Suite.

The right way to make the SDK available is to add the suite-sdk bin directory to your path, e.g. by adding the following to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
export PATH = $PATH:/usr/share/opengeo-suite/sdk/bin
```

Then you can choose your own place for creating sdk apps, e.g. in ~/projects/:

```
cd ~/projects
suite-sdk create myapp
```

Comment: Thanks @ahocevar, I just completed doing that. The reason I got confused was because I was able to locate the sdk/bin in the /usr but the doc states them to be extracted to /opt/opengeo/suite/sdk and i started thinking that it meant to cp teh sdk/ to /opt or something. But no problem, got it and it is working like a charm. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a machine that has the suite sdk you don't need to download the sdk. Its available under /usr/share/opengeo-suite/sdk and just put the bin directory on the PATH.

If you are on a machine that doesn't have an installation of the suite on it then you can download the sdk separately without requiring a full suite installation.